# Clearing data grid view after each selection of comboBox to retrive new data

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox

I have three categories in my employee view form and they are :
1- All Employee
2- Manager
3- Employee
These three categories are set as items in a comboBox each time I select one of the items it should display data about the selected item ... the problem is that the data grid view doesn't clear its first data to retrive the new one
my codes in the constructor is for displaying all employees

```
 da = new SqlDataAdapter("select empId as ID,empName ,empAdd,empBdate,empPhone1,empPhone2,empEmail,empSSN,empQualf from emp", cn);
            da.Fill(dt);
            empViewdgv.DataSource=dt;
```

and the other codes for retriving employee data on selection of combobox items

```
 private void empViewcmbo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (empViewcmbo.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                empViewdgv.DataSource = null;
                empViewdgv.Rows.Clear();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("select empId as ID,empName ,empAdd,empBdate,empPhone1,empPhone2,empEmail,empSSN,empQualf from emp", cn);
                da.Fill(dt);
                empViewdgv.DataSource = dt;
            }
            else if (empViewcmbo.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                empViewdgv.DataSource = null;
                empViewdgv.Rows.Clear();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("select empId as ID,empName ,empAdd,empBdate,empPhone1,empPhone2,empEmail,empSSN,empQualf from emp where empPerm='Manager'", cn);
                da.Fill(dt);
                empViewdgv.DataSource = dt;

            }
            else if (empViewcmbo.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                empViewdgv.DataSource = null;
                empViewdgv.Rows.Clear();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("select empId as ID,empName ,empAdd,empBdate,empPhone1,empPhone2,empEmail,empSSN,empQualf from emp where empPerm='Employee'", cn);
                da.Fill(dt);
                empViewdgv.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
```

When I select all employees it should display all employees but if I select Manager it should empty the data from datagridview first then display the data of managers and so on ...

Comment: Where do you initialize `dt` variable?

Comment: @arman1991 I declared it and initialized it before the constructor

Comment: It isn't clear enough what doest the `dt` and `cn` variable represent? Please edit your question and show us the whole solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call the `Clear()` method on DataTable before filling it up like

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select empId as ID,......", cn);
            dt.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt);
            empViewdgv.DataSource=dt;
```

Comment: this works with my idea thanks a lot you solved my problem